# Is there an equivalent to the Compiz Expose type plugin for Unity?

Tags: unity, 10.10, compiz, shortcut-keys

I've been giving 10.10 a spin on my netbook and it comes with Unity pre-enabled. Are there any equivalents to the plugins I use on full GNOME desktop, namely show all windows and show all windows on all workspaces? I can't seem to access anything other than keyboard shortcuts which don't list those operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is, but 11.04 Unity does use Compiz, and has that feature.

Comment: Anyway to trigger the workspace view with a keyboard shortcut? That's sort of the view I find useful.

Comment: It's Super-e, same as usual.

Comment: Odd - Super-e for me just numbers the entries on the left bar. None of the entries in "Keyboard Shortcuts" have Super prefixes.

Comment: I said it's coming in 11.04. There's nothing like it in 10.10, I'm afraid.

Comment: Apologies - I missed the context.

Answer (score 3):

You can install CompizConfig and then enable the Scale Plugin.